# SAS Enterprise-guide run time acummulated instead of individual process time

Tags: sql, sas, enterprise-guide

How do I show get the run time for the whole SAS project instead of the individual process run times? :
[image: Run Time example]

Would it possible to store the run times, so I can make statistics on how the job performs over time?

I hope you can point me in the right direction.

#Update:
Maybe my issue with @kermit solution is how my process is structured:
[image: Project structure]

Comment: Please post information as text not images which are blocked on my pc. Anyway we don't want to spend time retyping information before working on a solution for you.

Comment: Do you want to store the run times in a SAS table? a macro-variable?

Comment: @Kendle I am sorry but I don't think it would be possible to show that part of SAS EG as text. But if you have a solution I will gladly change it.

Comment: @Kermit a table would probably be easiest but it would not make a difference for me. Just some way to make it accesible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say you have the following SAS project

[image]

The first step would be to create the an empty log sas table in a pre-defined library.

```
data lib.log;
length date 8. run_time 8.;
format date datetime17. run_time time8.;
stop;
run;
```

What I would do now is adding a program (`START.sas`) before the first program and one after the very last program/export job (`END.sas`) to run in the process flow.

[image]

`START.sas`

```
libname lib "<path-to-your-folder>"
%let run_start = %sysfunc(time());
```

`END.sas`

```
%let run_end = %sysfunc(time());

proc sql;
insert into lib.log
values(%sysfunc(datetime()), %sysevalf(&run_end.-&run_start.))
;
quit;
```

With that, you only need to right-click on the start program and select `Run from selected item` and it will insert the date and run time into the log table at the end of the execution of your project.

[image]

Comment: Thank you I will give you an upvote tomorrow, I am just out of votes today.
I get this error when I run the code do you know why?:
"ERROR: Invalid physical name for library LIB."

Comment: You should set the libname path  `"<path-to-your-folder>"` to something appropriate.

Comment: Now I am getting this error in the last program:
` WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference RUN_END not resolved.
WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference RUN_END not resolved.
ERROR: A character operand was found in the %EVAL function or %IF condition where a numeric operand is required. The condition was: 
       &run_end.-49008.2660000324 
35         ;
           _
           79
ERROR 79-322: Expecting a ).`

Am I doing somthing wrong with the macro variable?

Comment: I forgot to add a `)` in the proc sql statement. Please see my edit.

Comment: At first it worked but now I am getting this error:
28         /*Create empty log SAS table*/
29         data lib.log;
30         length date 8. run_time 8.;
31         format date datetime17. run_time time8.;
32         stop;
33         run;

NOTE: Variable date is uninitialized.
NOTE: Variable run_time is uninitialized.
ERROR: Library LIB does not exist.

Comment: Make sure the library is correctly assigned and exist.